# How to get trace/exception data from Console C# application to the Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to put trace or exception data to the Application Insights. I am trying following code:

```
TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();
tc.InstrumentationKey = "xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx";
var traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry("Console trace critical", SeverityLevel.Critical);
tc.TrackTrace(traceTelemetry);
tc.TrackException(new ApplicationException("Test for AI"));
tc.Flush();
```

But it does not work, I can not find such traces or exceptions on the Application Insights dashboard, search or metric explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try adding a 5 seconds sleep before existing the process (after the flush) - IIRC flush only flushes the local buffer, and does not force send the telemetry to Application Insights

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that tc.Flush is not enough. I tried your code in console app and didn't see a request in Fiddler. When added Thread.Sleep(5000) then the exception showed up.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();
        tc.InstrumentationKey = "fe549116-0099-49fe-a3d6-f36b3dd20860";
        var traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry("Console trace critical", SeverityLevel.Critical);
        tc.TrackTrace(traceTelemetry);
        tc.TrackException(new ApplicationException("Test for AI"));
        tc.Flush();

        // Without this line Fiddler didn't show a request
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

And I was able to see an Exception in "Failures" screen.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's was the reason. However @Erang answered that an hour ago...

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to use `InMemoryChannel` if you are adding AI into the console/desktop/worker application and would like to [Flush synchronously](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/1648ecd5bf32cc151557d15cbb0886cb86e84270/src/Core/Managed/Shared/Channel/InMemoryChannel.cs#L142).

`InMemoryChannel` does not store data locally before it sends telemetry out, so there is no protection from data loss if anything happens on the wire. However, when you call `Flush()` it will actually try to send the telemetry instead of saving it to the disk.

Using `InMemoryChannel` will help prevent error-prone code like adding a `Sleep()` to give some time for `ServerTelemetryChannel` to send the locally stored telemetry items.

You'll need to replace the `ServerTelemetryChannel` via code or in the ApplicationInsights.coinfig file:

```
<TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes up to an hour for events/messages are visible in App Insights. I guess you have to be a little more patient for the message to show up.

Comment: I believe that it is not the case as it is an hour passed already. I've also tried to send the trace using EventFlow + Trace + Application Insights and it took about a minute to get the traces there...